# How to group by Max?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by, max

I'm having some trouble with a statement,
I have a table like this

| Player Number | Sport | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | soccer | 4/1 |
| 4 | basketball | 4/2 |
| 2 | basketball | 4/3 |
| 3 | soccer | 4/1 |
| 1 | baseball | 4/2 |
| 4 | basketball | 4/3 |
| 5 | soccer | 4/1 |
| 3 | baseball | 4/2 |
| 5 | soccer | 4/2 |
| 2 | basketball | 4/3 |
| 1 | soccer | 4/4 |
| 2 | baseball | 4/5 |
| 3 | soccer | 4/4 |
| 4 | soccer | 4/5 |
| 5 | soccer | 4/3 |
| 5 | basketball | 4/5 |

I'm trying to write a query that will give me a table that will group together the players by their most played sport so the end result will look like this:

| Sport | # of Players Who played the sport the most |
| --- | --- |
| Baseball | 2 |
| Basketball | 1 |
| Soccer | 2 |

I was able to write a statement that shows the number of times each player played a a specific sport but am having trouble getting the table to only select the rows with the highest number of plays and arranging it to be grouped by each sport.

```
Select distinct PLAYER_NUMBER, SPORT, Max(GAMES_PLAYED) as GAMES_PLAYED
FROM #temp
Group By SPORT, PLAYER_NUMER
order by GAMES_PLAYED desc
```

Comment: I don't think your desired results match your sample data? Baseball is only played by players 1,2,3 and then only once, so not going to be their most player sport.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your desired results match your sample data?

Anyway start with a query to get the number of plays per player, and use the `row_number` window function to determine which sport was played the most for each player (note what do you want to do in the case of a tie?). Then in the next query only use the sport with the most plays per player and group by sport.

```
with cte as (
    select *
        -- For each player get the sport with the most plays
        , row_number() over (partition by Player order by count(*) desc) rn
    from #temp
    group by Player, Sport
)
select Sport
    , count(*) [# of Players Who played the sport the most]
from cte
where rn = 1
group by Sport
order by Sport;
```

Returns:

| Sport | # of Players Who played the sport the most |
| --- | --- |
| basketball | 2 |
| soccer | 3 |

The following related query allows one to confirm the results shown above:

```
with cte as (
    select *
        , count(*) num
        , row_number() over (partition by Player order by count(*) desc) rn
    from #temp
    group by Player, Sport
)
select Player, Sport, num
from cte
order by Player, num desc;
```

Which shows for each player which sport was played the most i.e. its the first row for each player, and note baseball never shows up as the most played sport! The actual results are calculated using every `rn=1` because that is the sport most played per player.

| Player | Sport | num | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | soccer | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | baseball | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | basketball | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | baseball | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | soccer | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | baseball | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | basketball | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | soccer | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | soccer | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | basketball | 1 | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you might also get this by subqueries

```
select s.sport,
       count(distinct s.playdate) as times_played,
       (select max(t.players) from (
          select count(distinct s2.player) as players
          from   sports s2 
          where  s2.sport = s.sport 
          group by s2.sport, s2.playdate
          ) t
       ) as nbr_players
from   sports s
group by s.sport
```

this gets me

| sport | times_played | nbr_players |
| --- | --- | --- |
| baseball | 2 | 2 |
| basketball | 3 | 2 |
| soccer | 5 | 3 |

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=74e38415c37b24382212e43ab42e5f4f) here

Comment: haha - and you results are different again :)

Comment: @DaleK Yes, but who knows for sure what results the OP wants ? If you can spot a problem with my aproach then please share it, I know I still have lots to learn

Comment: @DaleK Where are the results different from yours ? I have the same nbr of players than you for soccer and basketball, I only also have a result for baseball which you dont

Comment: I have no idea whose are right :) but OP says "that will group together the players by their most played sport" which I took to mean only count the sports which are the most played by a given player. Baseball is not the most played by *any* player hence its not in my results. But who knows :) we can only wait for OP to comment.

Comment: @DaleK OKI see what you mean. My approach is more open, I just list the sports and the number of times played, and next to that I list the number of players that played it, and leave it up to OP to filter out what he does not wants. But as you say, we will have to wait until he/she comments